# pass varient from userform to module

Tags: excel, vba, userform

i've gat a moddule that calls the userform with the `userform.show`

in the userform ive added a refedit (budgetbox) and put the following code on the button

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()


'data as range
Dim budgetRng As Range
Set budgetRng = Range(BudgetBox)

'vars for foreach
Dim budgetRow() As Variant
Dim i As Integer, BudgetCell As Range
i = 0

'var to store data
Dim budgetName As String
Dim budgetMoney As Long

'getting the data from each cell and fill the nested arrays
For Each BudgetCell In budgetRng
    budgetName = BudgetCell.Value
    budgetMoney = BudgetCell.Offset(, 2)
    ReDim Preserve budgetRow(i)
    budgetRow(i) = Array(budgetName, budgetMoney)
i = i + 1
Next BudgetCell
end sub
```

to keep my work a bit organised, i would like to pass the array (budgetRow) to another module, but i cant seem te figure it out. i know is has something to do with setting the right things to public but that's it.

hope you guys can help me

Comment: Does your other sub have arguments? How are you trying to pass it?

Comment: to b honest i've no clue, litterly the only sub has the userform.show in it,. and now i would like to use the variant in the other module, but i dont know if i need to do something with get, and what i need to make public. or whatsoever, i am quite new to the programming world.

Comment: As an answer to your question: Put in a normal Module: Public budgetRow() As Variant and delete Dim budgetRow() As Variant from your Userform code.